# Applying auto layout constraints on custom UIView class Iphone.

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I am developing simple iPhone application in which I am using custom UIView class.
So when I apply that class to my view in story board it stop accepting my auto layout constraints. I tried to apply constraints in story board. So my custom UIView class looks like

```
 @implementation RoundedView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[super awakeFromNib];
UIRectCorner corners;
 … some code ...
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(self.radious, self.radious)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame         = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path          = maskPath.CGPath;
self.layer.mask         = maskLayer;

}
```

I am applying this class to my view in story board and its working fine but it is not listening for my constraints. So how to apply constraints in this situation. Any one knows about this one? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying it works without the awakeFromNib code?

Comment: did you try to set the maskLayer's needsDisplayOnBoundsChange to YES ?

Comment: you first need to set the maskLayer's frame too. I believe layers aren't affected by auto layout.

Comment: @cekisakurek can you please help me to do that?

Comment: @cekisakurek I tried with `maskLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;` But still it not working for me. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the frame of the layer to match its superview.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [maskLayer setFrame:self.bounds];
}
```

Comment: Adding more detail to this post explaining what it does may be useful to OP.

Comment: @cekisakurek thank you for your replay. I tried your solution. But it is not working for me.